# Listings and tabbing combined

Tags: listings, tabbing

I am trying to define a command which contains a tabbing environment. However, when I try to use the \lstinline command from the listings package it produces the "Improper Alphabetic Constant" error if I use a backslash.

When the same code is carried out without being contained within my defined command it works fine. Also, the \lstinline command works in the command without a backslash.

Why is this and how can I solve it so that I can place the tabbing environment in my defined command and still use \lstinline with a backslash?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\TabVerb[1]{\begin{tabbing}#1\end{tabbing}}

\begin{document}

\TabVerb{\lstinline|\Hello|}

\end{document}
```

For information, the following commands work without issue using the same document preamble.

```
\begin{tabbing}\lstinline|\Hello|\end{tabbing}
```

and

```
\TabVerb{\lstinline|Hello|}
```

Comment: Also I know it seems an odd thing to ask but the actual use involves a longer command which I defined and changes to various packages which I have made. I just simplified it down to the root of the problem. If you want more information let me know.

Comment: Escape the backslash: `\TabVerb{\lstinline|\\Hello|}`?

Comment: lstinline, like all verbatim commands can not be used in the argument or definition of another command

Comment: David test the last command I wrote with the document preamble I specified, or Troy's suggestion. I assure you that \lstinline will work in the argument of a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method provided by Troy works (not sure how to mark his comment as the answer to give him credit). Simply escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
\TabVerb{\lstinline|\\Hello|}
```

Alternatively, use the cprotect package alongside the command \cMakeRobust to prevent having many backslashes all over the place. (Simply place the following after the definition of the command)

```
\cMakeRobust\TabVerb
```

Note that the use of the cprotect package and \cMakeRobust also enables the use of \verb in the command if it is preferred over \lstinline.

Comment: Also if someone could copy and paste this answer and I will give you credit (preferably Troy), it seems odd that I would answer my own question